# Browser keeps loading ( Loading indicator keeps spinning) after running ajax function that uses json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I noticed that the "loading" indicator keeps spinning after running the ajax function below.  I tried several options but none work.  This happens in all 3 browsers (IE, Firefox and Chrome).  I used the "inspect element" from Chrome but nothing shows up on the network tab.  What am I doing wrong?

Also, as you may notice I tried to do a loop to print all the items without any success.  I would greatly appreciate it if someone could show me how to write a loop to print this information.  Thank you for your time.

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.wmata.com/Rail.svc/json/JStations?LineCode=GR&api_key=kfgpmgvfgacx98de9q3xazww',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            async: false,
            timeout: 5,
            success: function(data){
                // $.each(data, function() {
                // $.each(this, function(key,value){ 
                // alert (key);
                //})
                // $.each(data, function(i,v){
                //$('#div_id').append(v.Stations.Address.City); }
                var name = data.Stations[0].Address.City;
                var name2 = data.Stations[0].Code;
                var name3 = data.Stations[0].Name;

                document.write(name+" "+name2+" "+name3);
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code and instead of making the success function a property of the ajax, I binded it to the ajax itself like so.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.wmata.com/Rail.svc/json/JStations?LineCode=GR&api_key=kfgpmgvfgacx98de9q3xazww',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  async: false,
  timeout: 5,
}).success(function(data){
  $.each(data.Stations, function(i,v){
    $('body').append(' '+v.Address.City); 
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't see how that makes a difference. Also, you need `jsonp` instead of `json` because of SOP.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried the code you provided and the info prints out correctly but the browser's loading indicator keeps spinning.  I was reviewing my original code and after I removed the line "document.write(name+" "+name2+" "+name3);" the browser's loading indicator worked fine.  Is there another way to print out the contents?

Comment: oh yes I modified my answer and you can get it for example you want to get the name you can use v.Name give it a try or console.log(v) inside $.each

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much =)  I tried to vote up your response but it says "Vote Up requires 15 Reputation" Not sure what that means.  Thanks again though =)